# no of subspace in vector space V over finite field

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over $F_q$. Prove that no of the subspace of dimension $k(\leq n)$ is equal to no of the subspace of dimension $n-k$ in $V$.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers are given by the [Gaussian binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient) $\binom nk_q$ and $\binom{n-k}{k}_q$. Both coincide.

Reference: [How many k-dimensional subspaces there are in n-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb F_p$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-many-k-dimensional-subspaces-there-are-in-n-dimensional-vector-space-over)

Comment: I think there is a more straightforward (?) argument using the bijection between the $k$-dimensional subspaces of $V$ and $n-k$-dimensional subspaces of $V^{*}$. (And there's a small typo in your answer, I reckon.)