# How many subspaces of $\Bbb{F}_2^n$ have codimension 1

Tags: finite-fields

Let $\Bbb{F}_2^n$ be $n$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{F}_2$, the two element field.

Approximately how many distinct subspaces $U\le \Bbb{F}_2^n$ of codimension 1 (i.e., dimension $n-1$) are there for large $n$? More generally, for fixed $k$, how many distinct subspaces $U\le \Bbb{F}_2^n$ of codimension $k$ (i.e., dimension $n-k$) are there for large $n$? Here, subspaces $U,U'$ are considered distinct if they have different sets of elements, (i.e., we don't care about their bases or anything).

Comment: Do you know that a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ of codimension $k$ is the null space of a matrix with $k$ linearly independent rows? The proof of that works over arbitrary fields with no changes -- and of course when $k=1$, "linearly independent" is just "non-zero". So how many nonzero $1\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb F_2$ are there? Do any of them have the same null space?

Comment: This is [a duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/70801/11619). Many voters want to close this for other reasons, so I don't want to overrule them with my dupehammer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of all hyperplanes is in bijection with the set of lines of the dual space, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2^n$. So you have exactly
$$2^n-1$$

hyperplanes in $\mathbb{F}_2^n$.